# One user multiple shipping address how to make it as default

Tags: html, mysql, codeigniter

One user multiple shipping address how to make it as default,if click the make as default button,that address should be default and remaining all address shown the make as default button in a particular address box,except default address box.

**view page**

```
<?php foreach ($buyer_Address as $row) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default add_min_height">
            <div class="panel-heading">Default:</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="de" id="de" value="<?php echo $row->b_id; ?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <address><?php echo $row->b_fullname; ?><br>
                    <?php echo $row->b_street_address; ?>,<?php echo $row->b_locality ?>,<br>
                    <?php echo $row->b_landmark; ?>,
                    <?php echo $row->b_city; ?>, <?php echo $row->b_state; ?>,<?php echo $row->b_pincode; ?>
                    India
                    Phone number: <?php echo $row->b_mobile_number; ?></address>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/buyereditaddress?id=<?php echo $row->b_id; ?>" >Edit</a> 
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/buyerdeleteaddress?id=<?php echo $row->b_id; ?> ">Delete</a>
                <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
                <?php if ($row->status == '0') { ?>
                    <button type="submit" style="color:#337ab7;background: none !important;border: none;" name="default" id="default">Make as deafault</button> 
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**controller**

```
 public function defaultAddress() {
        $id = $this->input->post('de');
        $this->BuyerProfile_Model->defaultAddress($id);
        redirect('welcome/buyeraddresses');
    }
```

**model**

```
 function defaultAddress($id) {

        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->query("UPDATE buyer_order_address SET status = '0' WHERE b_id = '$id'");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE buyer_order_address SET status = '1' WHERE b_id = '$id'");
        $this->db->trans_complete();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the usage of status column in the table ?

Comment: if click the make as default button it will store in 1 status column...default is 0 @Rajeevbbqq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button as follow

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info mk-def" data-id="<?php echo $candidate_id; ?>" >Make as default</button>
```

Add following ajax script

```
$('.mk-def').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this);
    var candidate_id = btn.data('id');
    console.log(candidate_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?=base_url("index.php/BuyerProfile_Controller/defaultAddress"); ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "candidate_id="+candidate_id,
        dataType: 'TEXT',
        success: function (data) { console.log(data);
            btn.text('FINISHED'); location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

change your controller function as follow

```
public function defaultAddress() {
    $candidate_id = $this->input->post('candidate_id');
    $this->BuyerProfile_Model->defaultAddresss($candidate_id);      
}
```